# Only label selected breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Due to space constraints on the axes (log-transformed) I would like to only label select breaks while displaying breaks for a continuous sequence.  Of course the following results in an error:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-10,0,10,20,30),labels=c(-10,0,10,30))

Error: breaks and labels have unequal lengths
```

Is there a method to get around this problem?

Comment: You have 5 breaks, but only 4 labels. Are you trying:  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-10,0,10,20,30),labels=c(-10,0,10,20,30))

Comment: Yes, I would like to display 5 breaks on the graph but only label 4 of them

Comment: see if this works: scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-10,0,10,20,30),labels=c(-10,0,10,"",30))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-10,0,10,20,30), labels=c(-10,0,10,"",30))
```